# Need to achieve full width of page

Tags: html, css

New to coding and HTML. Not getting full width yet. Need full page height and width of these html divs. Previously its not coming with full width and height of it. Need to adjust it fully on viewport to appear it fully onto the page. Adjust it according to full page. Please help  what is the proper way in acheiving this task. I am trying to achieve full width out of it. Tried adjusting height and width fully. Appreciate the answer out of it.

**Screenshot for the specific code:**

[image]

Here is the HTML AND CSS code I pasted for the task:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  margin: auto;
}

.header {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.footer {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.left {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 700px;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 30px;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.right {
  width: 470px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.subleft {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 500px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
}

.subright {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(163, 33, 54);
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: block;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

.insidesubtopexaxt {
  width: 240px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: rgb(192, 207, 255);
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.insidesubbottomexaxt {
  width: 240px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.insidesubleft {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 195, 255);
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.equalmargindiv {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: brown;
  border: rgb(7, 7, 7) 1px solid;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.insidesubright {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Hello, Header</div>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="left">

    <div class="subleft">


      <div class="insidesubleft">

        <div class="equalmargindiv">

        </div>


      </div>
      <div class="insidesubright">


      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="subright">

      <div class="insidesubtopexaxt">

      </div>
      <div class="insidesubbottomexaxt">


      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

change the width of header,left and footer to be 100%

when set the width in [px] that mean it is fixed

```
 .header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  
  .footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  
  .left {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 30px;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>


    <style>
        body {
  display: grid;
  margin: auto;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.left {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 30px;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.right {
  width: 470px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.subleft {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 500px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
}

.subright {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(163, 33, 54);
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: block;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

.insidesubtopexaxt {
  width: 240px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: rgb(192, 207, 255);
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.insidesubbottomexaxt {
  width: 240px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.insidesubleft {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 195, 255);
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.equalmargindiv {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: brown;
  border: rgb(7, 7, 7) 1px solid;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.insidesubright {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">Hello, Header</div>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="left">

    <div class="subleft">


      <div class="insidesubleft">

        <div class="equalmargindiv">

        </div>


      </div>
      <div class="insidesubright">


      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="subright">

      <div class="insidesubtopexaxt">

      </div>
      <div class="insidesubbottomexaxt">


      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "viewport width" , this may fix

```css
.header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Comment: You have answered for header part full width only. Question for full width of all pages section. Read question properly to understand query. Try to answer to solve question completely.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is because you set width of 1200px to classes `.header`, `.footer` and `.left`. To achive full width you should just change it to 100% or 100vh.
If you set specific width, than the width of element will not change.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  margin: auto;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.left {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 30px;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.right {
  width: 470px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.subleft {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 500px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
}

.subright {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(163, 33, 54);
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: block;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

.insidesubtopexaxt {
  width: 240px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: rgb(192, 207, 255);
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.insidesubbottomexaxt {
  width: 240px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.insidesubleft {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 195, 255);
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.equalmargindiv {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: brown;
  border: rgb(7, 7, 7) 1px solid;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.insidesubright {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Hello, Header</div>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="left">

    <div class="subleft">


      <div class="insidesubleft">

        <div class="equalmargindiv">

        </div>


      </div>
      <div class="insidesubright">


      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="subright">

      <div class="insidesubtopexaxt">

      </div>
      <div class="insidesubbottomexaxt">


      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
```